# How can we set password for Community user?

Tags: experience-cloud

We are not using the registration process in the community site and for login, we are using the Login Discovery page.

We are creating community users on condition-based flow (Internally), so the passwordless functionality not working as passwordless

So, Now the problem is when the user is created they get a welcome email where they find a community link to log in, but as they click on the link they are directed to change the password first

So the Login discovery process is not running as fully password-less.

We want a passwordless experience for customers.

We also tried to set passwords for community users with different methods but, that is not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question might get more traction if you can share a bit more information about what you mean when you say that you "We want a passwordless experience for customers."

**TL;DR:** If passwords/credentials/authentication aren't necessary for this site, the solution is to make the site public and ungated--not to set meaningless passwords yourself if the site doesn't require authentication. However, if the opposite is true and you do want a private site that is only visible to your customers, but you don't want them to have to enter a password, then you need to setup an authentication process like Single Sign-On.

**More Detailed:** Experience Cloud is designed to work with both public and private pages. You can specify the type of access in your experience cloud settings and in specific pages:

- [Public Access Settings for Salesforce Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_public_access_settings.htm)
- [Control Public Access to Your Experience Builder Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_page_access_settings.htm&type=5)

If you need to setup SSO, the details will depend on your specific setup but it's pretty easy to use Salesforce as the identity provider for authentication. This is a good place to start:

- [Configure a Salesforce Authentication Provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/mobile-sdk/guide/sso-provider-sfdc.html)

Last, even though you say you aren't using the registration process, it sounds like you actually are if Salesforce is generating welcome emails for new users. You will want to disable the option to send a welcome email when a user is created. But like I said I'm not clear whether you intend your site to be un-gated (publicly available) or only visible by your customers.

Last, Salesforce by design does not allow you to (easily) set the passwords for users. This is a deliberate part of their security policy and is considered best practice. Technically, there is a way to do this but from the information that you've provided (or the information you haven't) in your question this is not something I would recommend. It is not intended to be used as a core part of any reasonable password policy.

In case that's not obvious, basically you should not know your user's passwords. Furthermore they should not be "knowable" at all by anyone but the user who set it. They should exist as a hash only and if a user can't remember their password, the solution is to let them reset it and make a new one. So  mentioning in your question that you have tried setting the passwords yourself also makes it hard to figure out what the requirements are for this solution.